# How do I get gcc-3.2.2 on RHEL 5?

Tags: gcc, redhat

We just had our hosting provider build out a new RHEL 5 box for us to test some legacy stuff on:

uname -a: Linux myserver.foo.com 2.6.18-164.9.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Dec 9 03:29:54 EST 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/redhat-release: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)

gcc -v: gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)

I'm having a hell of a time figuring out how to get gcc-3.2.2 installed on this machine:

- I can't seem to compile 3.2.2 with the gcc 4.1.2 compiler
- I can't seem to find a 3.2.2 installation via yum
- I'm afraid of what would happen if I rpm'd it manually

Any advice?

EDIT: thanks for the suggestions so far, but just to clarify - the "legacy stuff" I mentioned isn't actually my company's legacy stuff. It's a 3rd party package and I don't have access to the code (and wouldn't want to change it even if I did)

I guess I'll look into the chroot thing, because at this point going back to a different RHEL seems heartbreaking.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to install a RHEL 4 machine, it has gcc 3.4 which might work to build your stuff. Then you could try running the binaries on your RHEL 5.

It may just be easier to debug the legacy code to work on gcc 4.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is installing the rpm manually within a chroot. You would have to google a lot for the method but it should in theory work well. Alternatively you could just rewrite/update your legacy code (yes, I know it is easier said than done).